# Change color of progress bar background in android

Tags: android, xml, progress-bar

I have a Progressbar, which look is defined in a xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:id="@android:id/background">
        <shape>
            <corners  android:radius="@dimen/round_corners_elements" />
            <solid android:color="@color/blue_50" />

            <stroke android:width="1px" android:color="@color/light_gray" />
        </shape>
    </item>

    <item android:id="@android:id/progress">
        <clip android:clipOrientation="horizontal" android:gravity="left">
            <shape>
                <corners
                    android:radius="@dimen/round_corners_elements"
                   />
                <solid android:color="@color/signaling_color" />
                <stroke android:width="1px" android:color="@color/light_gray" />
            </shape>
        </clip>
    </item>

</layer-list>
```

But as i need to change the background color (blue50) to any other color dynamically, i failed. Anyone got an idea how i can change it programmatically? The progress can stay as it is. The special thing about is, that progress bar has round corners, which is necessary. I tried several approaches, but none worked for me.

> setBackgroundTintList didn't worked as is only available >API21

```
int[][] states = new int[][] { new int[] { android.R.attr.background }, new int[] { -android.R.attr.process } };
int[] colors = new int[] { Color.parseColor("#000000"), Color.BLACK };
ColorStateList myList = new ColorStateList(states, colors);
progressBar.setBackgroundTintList(myList);
progressBar.setBackgroundTintMode(PorterDuff.Mode.SRC_OVER);
```

> setBackgroundColor Also had no effect:

```
 progressBar.setBackgroundColor(ContextCompat.getColor(this, R.color.white));
```

Anyone got an idea?

Comment: change <solid android:color="@color/blue_50" /> to any other color which is defined in color.xml

Comment: Are you setting this xml drawable to `progressDrawable` attribute?

Comment: Yes it set as a drawable in the progressDrawable tag in the Layouter. I need to set it programmatically. I doesn't help me to set it at compile time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You will have to obtain the [`LayerDrawable`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/drawable/LayerDrawable.html) used by the `ProgressBar` and then either

- use [`findDrawableByLayerId(android.R.id.background)`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/drawable/LayerDrawable.html#findDrawableByLayerId(int)) to get the `Drawable` for that layer and make modifications to it at runtime; **or**
- create a new `Drawable` and call [`setDrawableByLayerId(android.R.id.background, newBackgroundDrawable)`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/drawable/LayerDrawable.html#setDrawableByLayerId(int,%20android.graphics.drawable.Drawable))

If I recall correctly, `<shape>` tags result in a [`GradientDrawable`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/drawable/GradientDrawable.html) being created at runtime by the system, and that conveniently has methods like [`setColor()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/drawable/GradientDrawable.html#setColor(int))

Comment: That solved the problem. I used the first version runtime.

Answer (score 0):

```
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
        progressBar.setProgressBackgroundTintList(ColorStateList.valueOf(tint));
    } else {
        LayerDrawable drawable = (LayerDrawable) progressBar.getProgressDrawable();
        Drawable background = new ColorDrawable(tint);
        drawable.setDrawableByLayerId(android.R.id.background, background);
        progressBar.setProgressDrawable(drawable);
    }
```